# VS 2015: Android - Failed with deployment errors

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, deployment

This is my first time with Xamarin/VS2015 for mobile development. I am not able to get a very simple "Hello World" program work on the simulator.

Detailed logs (from Console)

```
1>Starting deploy 5.2" Marshmallow (6.0.0) XXHDPI Phone ...
1>Starting emulator 5.2" Marshmallow (6.0.0) XXHDPI Phone ...
1>Validating emulator arguments...
1>Determining if emulator is already running...
1>Preparing virtual machine...
1>Launching emulator...
1>Emulator launched successfully.
1>Emulator 5.2" Marshmallow (6.0.0) XXHDPI Phone is running.
1>Deploying 5.2" Marshmallow (6.0.0) XXHDPI Phone ...
1>Build started.
1>C:\Users\Krishnan\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 169.254.249.147:5555 devices 
1>error: could not install *smartsocket* listener: cannot bind to 127.0.0.1:5037: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted. (10048)
1>could not read ok from ADB Server
1>* failed to start daemon *
1>error: cannot connect to daemon
1>List of devices attached
1>adb server version (32) doesn't match this client (36); killing...
1>
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\csc.exe /noconfig /nowarn:1701,1702,2008 /nostdlib+ /errorreport:prompt /warn:4 /define:DEBUG;TRACE;__XAMARIN_ANDROID_v1_0__;__MOBILE__;__ANDROID__;__ANDROID_1__;__ANDROID_2__;__ANDROID_3__;__ANDROID_4__;__ANDROID_5__;__ANDROID_6__;__ANDROID_7__;__ANDROID_8__;__ANDROID_9__;__ANDROID_10__;__ANDROID_11__;__ANDROID_12__;__ANDROID_13__;__ANDROID_14__;__ANDROID_15__;__ANDROID_16__ /errorendlocation /preferreduilang:en-US /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Xml.Xsl.Primitives.dll" /debug+ /debug:full /filealign:512 /optimize- /out:obj\Debug\HelloWorld.dll /ruleset:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\\Rule Sets\MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset" /target:library /utf8output MainActivity.cs Resources\Resource.Designer.cs Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs "C:\Users\Krishnan\AppData\Local\Temp\MonoAndroid,Version=v4.1.AssemblyAttributes.cs" obj\Debug\\TemporaryGeneratedFile_E7A71F73-0F8D-4B9B-B56E-8E70B10BC5D3.cs obj\Debug\\TemporaryGeneratedFile_036C0B5B-1481-4323-8D20-8F5ADCB23D92.cs obj\Debug\\TemporaryGeneratedFile_5937a670-0e60-4077-877b-f7221da3dda1.cs
1>HelloWorld -> D:\Projects\Xamarin\Android\Exercises\Hello\HelloWorld\HelloWorld\bin\Debug\HelloWorld.dll
1>  Processing: obj\Debug\res\layout\main.xml
1>  Processing: obj\Debug\res\values\strings.xml
1>Selected device is not running.
1>Build FAILED.
1>An error occured. See full exception on logs for more details.
1>Build started.
1>C:\Users\Krishnan\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 169.254.249.147:5555 devices 
1>error: could not install *smartsocket* listener: cannot bind to 127.0.0.1:5037: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted. (10048)
1>could not read ok from ADB Server
1>* failed to start daemon *
1>error: cannot connect to daemon
1>List of devices attached
1>adb server version (32) doesn't match this client (36); killing...
1>
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\csc.exe /noconfig /nowarn:1701,1702,2008 /nostdlib+ /errorreport:prompt /warn:4 /define:DEBUG;TRACE;__XAMARIN_ANDROID_v1_0__;__MOBILE__;__ANDROID__;__ANDROID_1__;__ANDROID_2__;__ANDROID_3__;__ANDROID_4__;__ANDROID_5__;__ANDROID_6__;__ANDROID_7__;__ANDROID_8__;__ANDROID_9__;__ANDROID_10__;__ANDROID_11__;__ANDROID_12__;__ANDROID_13__;__ANDROID_14__;__ANDROID_15__;__ANDROID_16__ /errorendlocation /preferreduilang:en-US /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Java.Interop.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v4.1\Mono.Android.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\mscorlib.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.Core.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.Xml.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.Xml.Linq.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\Microsoft.Win32.Primitives.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\Microsoft.Win32.Registry.AccessControl.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\Microsoft.Win32.Registry.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.AppContext.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Collections.Concurrent.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Collections.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Collections.NonGeneric.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Collections.Specialized.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.ComponentModel.Annotations.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.ComponentModel.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.ComponentModel.EventBasedAsync.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.ComponentModel.Primitives.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Console.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Data.Common.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Data.SqlClient.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Diagnostics.Contracts.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Diagnostics.Debug.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Diagnostics.Process.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Diagnostics.Tools.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Diagnostics.TraceEvent.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Diagnostics.TraceSource.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Diagnostics.Tracing.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Drawing.Primitives.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Dynamic.Runtime.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Globalization.Calendars.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Globalization.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Globalization.Extensions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.IO.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.IO.FileSystem.AccessControl.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.IO.FileSystem.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.IO.FileSystem.DriveInfo.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.IO.FileSystem.Watcher.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.IO.IsolatedStorage.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.IO.Pipes.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.IO.UnmanagedMemoryStream.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Linq.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Linq.Expressions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Linq.Parallel.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Linq.Queryable.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Net.AuthenticationManager.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Net.Cache.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Net.HttpListener.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Net.Mail.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Net.NameResolution.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Net.NetworkInformation.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Net.Ping.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Net.Primitives.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Net.Requests.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Net.Security.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Net.ServicePoint.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Net.Sockets.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Net.Utilities.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Net.WebHeaderCollection.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Net.WebSockets.Client.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Net.WebSockets.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.ObjectModel.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Reflection.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Reflection.Emit.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Reflection.Emit.ILGeneration.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Reflection.Emit.Lightweight.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Reflection.Extensions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Reflection.Primitives.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Reflection.TypeExtensions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Resources.ReaderWriter.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Resources.ResourceManager.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.VisualC.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Runtime.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Runtime.Extensions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Runtime.Handles.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Runtime.Numerics.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Security.AccessControl.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Security.Claims.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Security.Cryptography.Cng.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Security.Cryptography.Csp.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Security.Cryptography.DeriveBytes.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Security.Cryptography.Encryption.Aes.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Security.Cryptography.Encryption.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Security.Cryptography.Encryption.ECDiffieHellman.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Security.Cryptography.Encryption.ECDsa.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Security.Cryptography.Hashing.Algorithms.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Security.Cryptography.Hashing.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Security.Cryptography.RandomNumberGenerator.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Security.Cryptography.RSA.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Security.Principal.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Security.Principal.Windows.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Security.SecureString.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.ServiceModel.Duplex.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.ServiceModel.Http.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.ServiceModel.NetTcp.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.ServiceModel.Primitives.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.ServiceModel.Security.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Text.Encoding.CodePages.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Text.Encoding.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Text.Encoding.Extensions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Text.RegularExpressions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Threading.AccessControl.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Threading.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Threading.Overlapped.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Threading.Tasks.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Threading.Thread.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Threading.ThreadPool.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Threading.Timer.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Xml.ReaderWriter.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Xml.XDocument.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Xml.XmlDocument.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Xml.XmlSerializer.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Xml.XPath.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Xml.XPath.XDocument.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Xml.Xsl.Primitives.dll" /debug+ /debug:full /filealign:512 /optimize- /out:obj\Debug\HelloWorld.dll /ruleset:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\\Rule Sets\MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset" /target:library /utf8output MainActivity.cs Resources\Resource.Designer.cs Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs "C:\Users\Krishnan\AppData\Local\Temp\MonoAndroid,Version=v4.1.AssemblyAttributes.cs" obj\Debug\\TemporaryGeneratedFile_E7A71F73-0F8D-4B9B-B56E-8E70B10BC5D3.cs obj\Debug\\TemporaryGeneratedFile_036C0B5B-1481-4323-8D20-8F5ADCB23D92.cs obj\Debug\\TemporaryGeneratedFile_5937a670-0e60-4077-877b-f7221da3dda1.cs
1>HelloWorld -> D:\Projects\Xamarin\Android\Exercises\Hello\HelloWorld\HelloWorld\bin\Debug\HelloWorld.dll
1>  Processing: obj\Debug\res\layout\main.xml
1>  Processing: obj\Debug\res\values\strings.xml
1>Selected device is not running.
1>Build FAILED.
1>
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========[![enter image     `description here][1]][1]`
```

More logs when I open the project

```
[I:sdk]:                    Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Novell\Mono for Android\AndroidSdkDirectory found:
    Path contains adb in \platform-tools (C:\Users\Krishnan\AppData\Local\Android\sdk).
[I:sdk]:                    Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Novell\Mono for Android\AndroidNdkDirectory found:
    Path contains ndk-stack in \. (C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\AndroidNDK\android-ndk-r11c\).
[I:sdk]:                    Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Novell\Mono for Android\JavaSdkDirectory found:
    Path contains jarsigner.exe in \bin (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111).
[I:Unknown]:              Found Xamarin.Android 7.0.2
[I:Unknown]:              Found Android SDK. API levels: 16, 17, 18, 19, 21, 22, 23, 24
[I:]:                     Tracking android devices started
[D:]:                     Tracking avd started
[D:]:                     avd watcher *.ini path: 'C:\Users\Krishnan\.android\avd'
[D:]:                     avd watcher android path: 'C:\Users\Krishnan\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\android.BAT'
[W:]:                     Adb connection refused
[I:]:                     Starting Adb server (adb start-server)
[D:]:                     avd watcher: got device list from avd with 0 devices
[I:]:                     Adb start-server operation completed
[D:]:                     TrackDeviceTask got: 
[I:]:                     Got new device list from adb with 0 devices
[W:]:                     Adb connection reset
[I:]:                     Starting Adb server (adb start-server)
[I:]:                     Adb start-server operation completed
[D:]:                     TrackDeviceTask got: 
[I:]:                     Got new device list from adb with 0 devices
```

Comment: Which simulator are you using. It says that the device which you selected is not running.

Answer (score 0):

ADB lets you connect to an android emulator/device to install/debug your app. It says your device is not running, therefore ADB fails to connect to it. Make sure you have an android device connected with debug mode enabled and debug permission from your pc, or a valid android emulator, which you can get in the tools > android > device manager.

Comment: Yep. That's where I am in need of help. I see 2 errors, may be they are related or may be not
1. adb server version (32) doesn't match this client (36); killing...
2. C:\Users\Krishnan\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 169.254.109.177:5555 devices 
2>error: could not install *smartsocket* listener: cannot bind to 127.0.0.1:5037: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted. (10048)
2>could not read ok from ADB Server

I have no clue to what's wrong and how to fix it

Comment: It looks like your emulator does launch but ADB doesn't have access. I had problems before when using an emulator that I started in another instance of visual studio. Make sure this isnt the case. Also, don't just mention errors, include them.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Issue has got nothing to do with Android simulators or Genymotion. Its more to do with Oracle VirtualBox on Windows 10.

I installed Virtualbox version 5.0.4.*. All my attempts to open it manually failed. Android virtual device(s) use VB for all valid reasons. Failure to open VB will fail simulators too.

Searching web, I confirmed this perpetual issue on Windows 10.

**Solution**

- Uninstalled VB 5.0.*
- Installed VB 5.1.* from https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Testbuilds

No more naggers. Happy coding!!!